# Celery all generated tasks status

Tags: django, queue, celery

Django produces multiple *Celery* tasks through chains in one script run (f.e. if / is opened in browser, 1000 tasks are called by delay method).

I need something that will restrict new task generation, if tasks, queued in previous script run, are still running.

Answer (score 0):

You need a distributed lock for this, which celery doesn't offer natively.

For these kinds of locks I've found `redis.Lock` useful to most cases. If you need a semaphore, you can use redis' atomic incr/decr functions along with some kind of watchdog mechanism to ensure your processes are still running.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the number of tasks of one type running at the same time by setting:

```
rate_limit = “1000/m”
```

=> only 1000 tasks of this type can run per minute.
(see http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#list-of-options)